# MySQL Multiple Queries or use the IN(value1,value2,value3)

Tags: mysql, performance

Just a short introduction:

I have one table `t1( id(mediumint), string(varchar(45) )` both belong to primary key.

I need to find in this table 5 strings, let's say. And this table is like 5M + rows.

What would be faster?

1. One query using `IN()`:

   ```
   SELECT id, string FROM t1 WHERE string IN (value1,value2,...,value5)
   ```

   or
2. Five queries, one for each value:

   ```
   SELECT id, string FROM t1 WHERE string = value1
   SELECT id, string FROM t1 WHERE string = value2
   '
   '
   SELECT id, string FROM t1 WHERE string = value5
   ```

The application server and database server will be on the same network (100Mbit or 1Gbit, not sure yet), not on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks Radu, if I had reputation I would give you a +1 ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, using a single query is likely to be faster than using multiple queries, since it avoids the overhead of parsing, sending the queries and receiving multiple separate responses, and it allows for better optimization. When in doubt, profile.

Also keep in mind the length of the query. Most database servers have a limit of how long the query string can be. So, if you have long lists of values, you should send them in batches.

Comment: Alternatively (to long and/or recompiled SQL) you can use parametrised queries (AKA PreparedStatements) and it will solve most of mentioned problems in a moment.

Comment: Can you give a reference about your answer please?

Answer (score 2):

One query using the IN() should be faster.  Make sure you have an index with "string" as the first column.

Comment: Yes, if you have an index on columns A, B and query only on B, mysql cannot use that index.  If you query on only A it can use it.

Comment: @JakeArmstrong, think of indexes as trees. The first level is the branch, the second level are the leaves. If the first level contains IDs, then you will need to sift through all branches to get to the indexed leaves representing the strings.

Comment: Well, so if I need to select on both Should I have then two separated indexes? It will multiply the data right?

Comment: @JakeArmstrong, you should create compound indexes if you need to search for the two things together. For example, if you had an index on column #1 (numbers), the index could contain: "1, 2, 3, ...". If you had one on column #2 (strings), it could contain: "abc, def, ghi, ...". If you had a compound one on #1 and #2, it could contain: "1-abc, 1-bcd, ..., 2-def, 2-efg, ...". So now when you search for "1", it can easily find all the "1-abc, 1-bcd, ..." records. If you search for "2-def", again, easy to find. But if you search for "efg", as you can see, there's no direct path to it => full scan.

Comment: @JakeArmstrong, you should always create indexes based on how the application is used. For example, if the application is often used to search for IDs and strings in the same query, then a compound index on the two will give the best performance. If however the application is mainly used for either searching IDs or strings, in different queries, a compound index will be of no extra help for searching IDs, and useless for searching strings, in which case you'll need 2 indexes, one for IDs, one for strings.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I will give you the right answer since you also solved quite a few other problems I had and also edited my post! :-) this query length limit I didn't know and would for sure get me... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only time when having multiple queries will be faster and more efficient is when you need complex and possibly multiple JOINs in your queries, than it is better to get separate results from separate tables and JOIN them in memory in your application. **Mainly as a way of saving transfer time/bandwidth.**
Every other time it is best to run single query.

Comment: Does that also applies to a MySQL cluster running all in memory? I didn't specify it on my question but I'm curious about...

Comment: @JakeArmstrong  I was actually referring to the situation (fairly common in business logic queries) which I had to deal with: the query was something like `select customer.id + customer.address + customer.furtherDetails + supplier.id + supplier.address + supplier.furtherDetails + alternativeSupplier.id + alternativeSupplier.address + alternativeSupplier.furtherDetails` (and more). The single resultset contained A LOT of duplicate information per record AND a lot of records. My solution was to run few separate queries dramatically cutting data transfer time.

Comment: But I'm not sure you need to retrieve all fields you use in a join. It's possible to join like five tables (a,b,c,d,e) and retrieve one field from a and one from e, etc... so if you need the fields then retrieving them together or separated should take the same, right?

Comment: @JakeArmstrong, depending on database server, `JOIN`s can come with different performance penalties. I also often found that doing the `JOIN` manually in application code (`SELECT id FROM t1`, `SELECT FROM t2 WHERE id IN (... what I get from t1 ...)`) achieves better to much better performance when using MySQL. I recently started using MongoDB, which does not offer any support for `JOIN`, and I never missed it. Also, since it doesn't support `JOIN`, this allows for much easier scaling.

Comment: @JakeArmstrong When you need to get and display BOTH customer details/address,  supplier details/address and alternative supplier details/address could you explain to me how you could avoid a long record with unnecessarily duplicated data possible BOTH within the same record and across multiple records? To understand completely what I am talking about try to write a SQL to get the data. Then write SQL to get data from separate tables separately...
And I am not even talking about (possible, as I did NOT encounter DB engines wit such problems) inefficiencies of JOINs.